# Vim LaTeX-suite: set keybinding to compile and view pdf

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-latex

I'm new to Vim and it's just fantastic!
Now I would like to set up the Latex-suite with reverse searching and found [this easy way](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_can_interact_with_xdvi) by compiling to xdvi. But sometimes, I need the .`pdf`.

What I would like:

- `\ld` : save, compile to `.xdvi` and open the default `.xdvi` viewer
- `\lv`: save, compile to `.pdf`  and open the default `.pdf`  viewer

How can I do this? Is it possible to save the multi-file LaTeX-project?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [this Wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compiling_LaTeX_from_Vim#Vim-Latex_plugin) about options to compile LaTeX from Vim. The [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) plugin should cover all your needs (e.g. [Multiple file LaTeX projects](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html)), you can find the full documentation [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) or with `:help latex-suite` from within Vim.

An alternative method is to tweak the `&makeprg` option in order to change the program used by the `:make` command. From [the same article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compiling_LaTeX_from_Vim#Manual_setup); if using `pdflatex`, add this to `ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
let b:tex_flavor = 'pdflatex'
compiler tex
set makeprg=pdflatex\ \-file\-line\-error\ \-interaction=nonstopmode
set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
```

See `:h :_%` and `:h :_#` for their special meaning in `&makeprg`.
Note that `&errorformat` is used to describe the output, available in the `quickfix` window after each run. [Here](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/compiler/tex.vim) is how those are "dynamically" defined in the plugin for LaTeX-suite.

Once you are able to execute `:make` successfully, just add a mapping to save, compile and open (this assumes the file is created with the same location and name, and that `open` is an actual PDF viewer in your PATH):

```
:nnoremap \lv :w<CR>:make<CR>:!open expand('%:r').pdf<CR>
```

For more:

- `:h :nnoremap`
- `:h expand()`
- `:h filename-modifiers`

Comment: Thank you! I've changed to vimtex because it's supporting inverse search with zathura out of the box.